# What is the commmand line to add watermark while screen recording using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, command, watermark, video-watermarking

I tried to record screen using ffmpeg commmand line. So, I have complete it using this commmand.
ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 1500M -f -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:02:00 -framerate 30 0 0 -probesize 10M 1920 1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 30 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.avi".

Now, I want to add watermark while recording video.
If you have good experience this field, Please give me good advice.
Thanks for your attention.
Sincerely.

Comment: Please share its urls,  I can't find it.

Comment: Please share its urls

Comment: Add the overlay filter: `ffmpeg -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:02:00 -framerate 30 -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -i watermark.png -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -crf 30 -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay,format=yuv420p" output.avi` See duplicate link for more info and how to position.

Comment: Mr llogan, Thank you very much.

Comment: Mr llogan. I'm trying to record audio, screen and watermark.  ffmpeg.exe -rtbufsize 1500M -f dshow -i audio="virtual-audio-capturer" -f -y -rtbufsize 100M -f gdigrab -t 00:02:00 -framerate 30 -offset_x 0 -offset_y 0 -probesize 10M -video_size 1920x1080 -draw_mouse 1 -i desktop -i watermark.png -c:v libx264 -r 30 -preset ultrafast -tune zeorlatency -crf 30 -filter_complex "[0][2]overlay,format=yuv420p" output.avi"   But I get the error like this "Stream specifier '' in filtergraph description [0][2]overlay,format=yuv420p matches no streams."

Comment: Yong Ju: @llogan will probably not see what you wrote unless you use the name tagging feature (type @ and then start typing the name and it should show up). Anyway, since your question doesn't seem to be related to a programming problem, my suggestion was to close this question and that you ask it on [video.stackexchange.com](https://video.stackexchange.com/?tags=ffmpeg) instead where they focus more on using the `ffmpeg` application (and similar applications).

Comment: @YongJu You are attempting to use the audio input with overlay. Use `[1][2]overlay`. (And Ted is correct: I did not get a notification of your response.)